# Can you build an Outlook 2010 add in using .NET 4.5 framework in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, outlook

I recently built a Outlook 2010 add in (in C#) using the .NET 4.0 Client profile framework in VS2010 but I would like to use the System.Net.Http library, which is under the .NET 4.5 framework and so I installed VS2012 to be able to do this. However, I only have Outlook 2010 installed on my machine and so want to be able to run the add-in from VS2012 in Outlook 2010 but I'm unable to do so at the moment as when I go to debug this in VS2012 it says that I don't have the correct version of Outlook.
So far in VS2012 I can only see options to build Outlook 2013 add-ins with the .NET 4.5 framework and not Outlook 2010, which can only been seen under the .NET 4.0 framework. Is there any way I can somehow use the System.Net.Http library with my Outlook 2010 add-in and have it available to run on Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can build and run an Outlook 2010 add-in in VS2012. You can read more about that in the [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx) article in MSDN.

Most probably you need to choose the .Net framework 4.0 in the Create New project wizard in Visual Studio to get the template visible and available:

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that under the .NET 4.0 framework I cannot use the System.Net.Http library as that is only available under the .NET 4.5 framework unless there is another way I can use that library in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Okay. In that case you can create a project with the target framework set to 4.5. Add the required reference and then you can replace the Outlook interop reference with the one which corresponds to Outlook 2010. Thus, you will be able to debug it. VSTO uses interop assemblies to detect which Office application version to run for debugging.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm still unable to debug the application. I have replaced the interop reference to point to version 14 (which I believe is for Outlook 2010) but I still get the wrong version error when trying to debug.

Comment: Try to set the External program to start on the project properties page.